# SFTP upload of files that were created since the last run

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, windows-task-scheduler, winscp-net

I am very new to PowerShell and I am in the process of writing a script that performs an SFTP file transfer via WinSCP. I will then be creating a Task on Windows Task Scheduler to run this script every 15 minutes indefinitely. Currently I have this line of code that gets all files in a directory within the last write time that was more than 20 seconds prior:

```
$filelist = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\lsarm\IHS\test |
    where { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddSeconds(-20) }
```

I have been told that this needs to be changed so that it gets all files since the last time the Task was ran (15 minutes prior) instead, but I have had very little luck in finding the answer.

I have tried using `Get-ScheduledTask` but that only seems to get me basic information about the task and doesn't seem like it is what I need for my script. Also, I have already downloaded the WinSCP `.dll` file and unblocked it in PowerShell. Any help is welcome, TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Using the time the task ran the last time is imo not reliable. There's still space for you to miss some files or transfer some files repeatedly.

Instead, consider remembering the timestamp of the most recent uploaded file.

Assuming you use `Session.PutFiles`, you can use code like this:

```
$transferResult =
  $session.PutFiles($sourcePath, $destPath, $False, $transferOptions)
$transferResult.Check()
 
# Find the latest uploaded file
$latestTransfer =
  $transferResult.Transfers |
  Sort-Object -Property @{ Expression = { (Get-Item $_.Source).LastWriteTime } } `
              -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 1
```

And save the `$latestTransfer` to a file for the next run. Or loop the code with 15 minutes delay, instead of scheduling it every 15 minutes.

Another option is to remember the already transferred files.

Both options are in more details covered in:
[How do I transfer new/modified files only?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_modified_files)